# how to modify an excel or google sheet dynamic array's output

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

To keep it short, see picture

[image: Here the area of data is Ch!b2:d30, but in reality it's Ch!b2:d]
I tried chatgpt, didn't really understood what i wanted, all solutions given were about getting every second row of data from source and paste it.
I do not want to run a script behind, the file is a template for future files, and is used by multiple persons (auth every person for each file, might get boring)
Any ideas?

Comment: Decide which package either Excel or Googlesheets as they are different.

Comment: The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Comment: any of both. google would be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for EXCEL:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A1:L1,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,"",b))),,2)
```

Result:

[image]

Google Sheets:

```
=choosecols((REDUCE("",A1:L1,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,"",b)))),sequence(1,columns(A1:L1)*2-1,3,1))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: awesome. Ty very much! It solves 1 row of the three row matrix, but i copied it in three rows, not really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `torow()` and `tocol()`, like this:

```
=byrow(A1:L3, lambda(row, let( 
  blankRow, map(row, lambda(_, )), 
  torow(tocol(vstack(row, blankRow), 0, true)) 
)))
```

See [torow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187459) and [tocol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258).

Answer (score 0):

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:D3)),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,{""},CHOOSECOLS(A1:D3,y)))),""),,2)
```

This works for data in range A1:D3 in my sheet.